# How to properly manage Python application dependencies?

Tags: python, pip, dependency-management, setup.py, pyproject.toml

### Problem

I have a Python application (not library) that i want to publish as a `pip` installable package. In order for the application to install and run predictably with `pip install` now, in a month or in 2 years i want to pin all dependencies, for example with [`pip-tools`](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools#pip-tools--pip-compile--pip-sync)

### Current workflow

Currently for my package there are 3 files involved:

- `requirements.in`: Listing the direct application dependencies. No or loose version pinning. Source file for `pip-compile`.
- `requirements.txt`: Full lockfile for all dependencies *(also transitive)* generated with `pip-compile` from `requirements.in`. The `requirements.txt` file is not part of the Python wheel, so `pip install` cannot use it.
- `setup.py`: Here in `install_requires` i read in the compiled `requirements.txt` so that the complete, pinned dependencies find their way in the wheel metadata for `pip install`. *(Example see below)*:

```py
# setup.py
setup(
  ...
  # pseudocode
  "install_requires": pip.parse(Path(".")/"requirements.txt")
  ...
)
```

### Questions

- Is that how it should be done or are there better approaches?
- What is considered best practice for Python application dep. management? Pinning all deps. in setup.py, also transitive ones? Or just the direct ones *(trusting them with the pinning/locking of their deps.)*?
- How does the approach to dynamically read in the `requirements.txt` translate to the modern, declarative approach with `pyproject.toml`? Or does it not, and instead of the automation i need to manually copy the compiled `requirements.txt` content in the `pyproject.toml` dependencies section?